# Applying CSS properties dynamically using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a mobile ePub reader. One functionality I would like to implement is adding expandable notes, which would be tied to highlighted words.

I would like to know how to iterate over the set of created marginalia and apply the background color and offset that I got for each highlight. In other words, each marginale should have the same background color as its highlight, and have the same offset from the top of the screen (so that both are aligned).

Thanks,

```js
function Marginale(offset, color) {
  this.offset = offset;
  this.color = color;
}

(function createMarginalia() {

  let $highlights;
  $highlights = $('.highlight');

  $highlights.each(function() {

    let color, offset, screen;
    let $marginalia;

    color = $(this).css('backgroundColor');
    offset = $(this).position().top;
    screen = $('#screen');

    screen.append('<div class="marginale"></div>');

    $marginalia = $('.marginale');

    $marginalia.each(function() {
      $(this).css({
        'backgroundColor': color,
        'top': offset
      });
    });

  });

})();

(function hideNavOnScroll() {

  let nav, screen, yPos;
  nav = $('nav');
  yPos = 0;
  screen = $('#screen');

  screen.scroll(function() {
    let yOffset = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (yOffset > yPos) {
      nav.fadeOut();
    } else {
      nav.fadeIn();
    }

    yPos = yOffset;
  });

})();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
:root {
  --dpi: 2;
  --texidiumGreen: #00857c;
  --slateGrey: #47484a;
  --lightGrey: #eee;
  --mediumGrey: #aaa;
  --redHighlightColor: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  --greenHighlightColor: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);
  --blueHighlightColor: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
  --yellowHighlightColor: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2);
  --grayHighlightColor: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  --fontSize: 12.5px;
  --appBarHeight: 54px;
  --bottomBarHeight: 64px;
  --contentPadding: 40px;
  --marginaleSize: calc(var(--contentPadding) - 8px);
}

body {
  background-color: var(--lightGrey);
}

#phone {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px var(--mediumGrey);
}

#screen {
  width: calc(750px / var(--dpi));
  height: calc(1334px / var(--dpi));
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: white;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

#app-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--appBarHeight);
  background-color: var(--texidiumGreen);
}

#bottom-bar {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--bottomBarHeight);
  background-color: var(--slateGrey);
}

.hide-nav {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#content {
  padding-right: var(--contentPadding);
  padding-left: var(--contentPadding);
  font-size: var(--fontSize);
  font-family: Roboto;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

h1:first-of-type {
  margin-top: calc(var(--fontSize) * 2 + var(--appBarHeight));
}

h1 {
  margin-top: calc(var(--fontSize) * 2);
  font-size: calc(var(--fontSize) * 2);
  font-weight: bold;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: calc(var(--fontSize) * 1.5);
  font-weight: bold;
}

p {
  margin-top: var(--fontSize);
}

p:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: var(--fontSize);
}

.highlight.highlight-red {
  background-color: var(--redHighlightColor);
}

.highlight.highlight-green {
  background-color: var(--greenHighlightColor);
}

.highlight.highlight-blue {
  background-color: var(--blueHighlightColor);
}

.highlight.highlight-yellow {
  background-color: var(--yellowHighlightColor);
}

.highlight.highlight-gray {
  background-color: var(--grayHighlightColor);
}

.marginale {
  width: var(--marginaleSize);
  height: var(--marginaleSize);
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: var(--marginaleSize);
  color: white;
  /*background: black;*/
}

.marginale {
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.marginale:before {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: '\f249';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="phone">
  <div id="screen">
    <nav id="app-bar"></nav>
    <div id="content">
      <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste laboriosam magni corporis, similique labore ipsa, consequuntur eos, odit corrupti quaerat necessitatibus doloremque enim? Numquam itaque velit dolor explicabo aut, laborum?</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste laboriosam magni corporis, similique labore ipsa, consequuntur eos, odit corrupti quaerat necessitatibus doloremque enim? <span class="highlight highlight-red">Numquam itaque velit dolor explicabo aut, laborum?</span>        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste laboriosam magni corporis, similique labore ipsa, consequuntur eos, odit corrupti quaerat necessitatibus doloremque enim? Numquam itaque velit dolor explicabo aut, laborum?</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste laboriosam magni corporis, similique labore ipsa, consequuntur eos, odit corrupti quaerat necessitatibus doloremque enim? Numquam itaque velit dolor explicabo aut, laborum?</p>
      <h2>Dolor Sit Amet</h2>
      <p><span class="highlight highlight-green">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste laboriosam magni corporis, similique labore ipsa, consequuntur eos, odit corrupti quaerat necessitatibus doloremque enim? Numquam itaque velit dolor explicabo aut, laborum?</span></p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste laboriosam magni corporis, similique labore ipsa, consequuntur eos, odit corrupti quaerat necessitatibus doloremque enim? Numquam itaque velit dolor explicabo aut, laborum?</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste laboriosam magni corporis, similique labore ipsa, consequuntur eos, odit corrupti quaerat necessitatibus doloremque enim? Numquam itaque velit dolor explicabo aut, laborum? Lorem ipsum
        dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste laboriosam magni corporis, similique labore ipsa, consequuntur eos, odit corrupti quaerat necessitatibus doloremque enim? Numquam itaque velit dolor explicabo aut, laborum?</p>
      <p><span class="highlight highlight-yellow">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste laboriosam magni corporis, similique labore ipsa, consequuntur eos, odit corrupti quaerat necessitatibus doloremque enim? Numquam itaque
        velit dolor explicabo aut, laborum? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <span class="highlight highlight-blue">Iste laboriosam magni corporis, similique labore ipsa, consequuntur eos, odit corrupti quaerat necessitatibus doloremque enim?</span>        Numquam itaque velit dolor explicabo aut, laborum?</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste laboriosam magni corporis, similique labore ipsa, consequuntur eos, odit corrupti quaerat necessitatibus doloremque enim? Numquam itaque velit dolor explicabo aut, laborum? Lorem ipsum
        dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <span class="highlight highlight-gray">Iste laboriosam magni corporis, similique labore ipsa, consequuntur eos, odit corrupti quaerat necessitatibus doloremque enim? Numquam itaque velit dolor explicabo aut, laborum?</span></p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iste laboriosam magni corporis, similique labore ipsa, consequuntur eos, odit corrupti quaerat necessitatibus doloremque enim? Numquam itaque velit dolor explicabo aut, laborum?</p>
    </div>
    <nav id="bottom-bar"></nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add code in snippet runner. It will run live on the page.